# find the first maximum occurence in vector

Tags: r

Let's say I have a vector

```
x <- c(300, 320, 342, 355, 399, 453, 500, 532, 2, 3, 4, 5, 100, 300, 500, 550, 2, 3)
```

As you can see it has some increasing values, then the values are decreasing, then increasing again and so on.

The point where the first decreasing is spotted is in value 532 followed by value 2.So, at this point I want to add to 532 the value 2, so I have 534 now.Then add to 534 the value 3, then value 4 then value 5 and so on.

So, I cumsum the values after the first maximum occurence which is value 532.

So, my result would be:

```
300, 320, 342, 355, 399, 453, 500, 532, 534, 537, 541, 546, 646, 964, 1446, 1996, 1998 , 2001
```

I am trying:

```
MY_FUNC <- function(Values)
{

    Values <- Values[!is.na(Values)]

    max_val = 0
    index = 0;
    for (i in 1:length(Values))
    {
        if (Values[i] > max_val)
        {
            max_val = Values[i]
            index = i;
            #break when first occurence found
        }
    }
    new_vec <- Values[index] + cumsum(Values[(index + 1):length(Values)])
    new_vec

}

x <- c(300, 320, 342, 355, 399, 453, 500, 532, 2, 3, 4, 5, 100, 300, 500, 550, 2, 3)
MY_FUNC(x)
```

but I don't know how to find the first maximum occurence and break of the loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `diff` and `which.max` to find the first drop in value and then concatenate values before that point and `cumsum` of values after that point together.

```
first_drop <- which.max(diff(x) < 0)
c(x[1:(first_drop - 1)], cumsum(x[first_drop:length(x)]))

#[1]  300  320  342  355  399  453  500  532  534  537  541  546  646  946 1446 1996
#[17] 1998 2001
```

---

We can write this in function if needed

```
MY_FUNC <- function(x) {
  first_drop <- which.max(diff(x) < 0)
  c(x[1:(first_drop - 1)], cumsum(x[first_drop:length(x)]))
}

MY_FUNC(x)
# [1]  300  320  342  355  399  453  500  532  534  537  541  546  646  946 1446
#[16] 1996 1998 2001
```

Comment: Thanks! Very nice solution! (upv)

Comment: If we say that we have a second drop as in the above example of `x`, how can we define it?Because, `which.max(diff(x) < 0)` returns only the first index.

Comment: `dropAfter <- min(which(diff(x) < 0));c(x[1:dropAfter], cumsum(x[dropAfter:length(x)])[-1])` I solved it like this.

Comment: @George Using `which` would give you all the drops, then you can subset it as per your need. `which(diff(x) < 0)`. If you want second drop, do `which(diff(x) < 0)[2]` and so on.

Comment: @RonakShah:Ok, that is what I wanted!diff(x) <0 has an index also!Thanks

Comment: @AndreElrico:Ok, thanks for the tip.I want to use the index of diff(x)<0